# Python 3: Server socket not closing properly, infinite loop of blank messages received

Tags: sockets, python-3.3

**EDIT: I solved this question myself, look at the first answer if you have a similar issue**

I am new to sockets and made a client-server test modifying one example, it sends and receives data ok but when closing the server get caught in a loop receiving blank messages and I can't find out why even though I use shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) to close the connection immediately according to the documentation.

I had to use two cmd of windows for each one (server and client) because when running first the server in idle and then the client I got in client_example ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it here is the code. Anyways, here it is the sequence I tried:

(in the client console):

```
c:\python33\python client_example.py
SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):Hi
SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):q
```

(in the server console):

```
c:\python33\python server_example3.py
TCPServer Waiting for client on port 7000
I got a connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 49263)
RECEIVED: b'Hi'
RECEIVED: b''
RECEIVED: b''
RECEIVED: b''
RECEIVED: b''
RECEIVED: b''
....                 <---After I did CTRL+C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_example.py", line 19, in <module>
    print("RECEIVED:",data)
  File "c:\python33\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Here is the code of the server and client:

server_example.py:

```
#TCP server example
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 7000))
server_socket.listen(5)

print("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 7000")

while 1:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("I got a connection from ", address)
    while 1:
        data = client_socket.recv(32)
        if (data == 'q' or data == 'Q'):            
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            client_socket.close()
            break;
        else:
            print("RECEIVED:",data)
```

client_example.py:

```
# TCP client example
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 7000))
while 1:
    data = input( "SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):" )
    if (data != 'Q' and data != 'q'):
        my_bytes = bytearray()
        for c in data:
            my_bytes.append(ord(c))
        client_socket.send(my_bytes)
    else:
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        client_socket.close()
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb that I solved this thing after 11 minutes of posting the question when I was unable to solve it for 2 hours...

The problem was that I was comparing data with the string 'q' which was correct in python 2 but in python 3 what is being sent are bytes, b'q' <> 'q' ...

Here is the corrected code:

server_example.py

```
#TCP server example
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 7000))
server_socket.listen(5)

print("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 7000")

while 1:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("I got a connection from ", address)
    while 1:
        data = client_socket.recv(32)
        print("RECEIVED:",data)
        if (data == b'q' or data == b'Q'):            
##          client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            client_socket.close()
            break;
    break;
```

client_example.py

```
# TCP client example
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 7000))
while 1:
    data = input( "SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):" )
    if (data != 'Q' and data != 'q'):
        my_bytes = bytearray()
        for c in data:
            my_bytes.append(ord(c))
        client_socket.send(my_bytes)
    else:
        my_bytes = bytearray()
        my_bytes.append(ord(data))
        client_socket.send(my_bytes)        
##      client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        client_socket.close()
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming you're going to get the Q. You should also engage in the same processing when you get EOS from read, whatever form that takes in Python.

Answer (score 0):

@EJP : By EOS you mean end of stream? If so you are right, this example was a very simple one to get started in which I overlooked details like these.

Anyway I found that using this check in the server it is solved:

```
data = input( "SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):" )
if (data == b''):
    break;
```